# Remove apps from Ubuntu Live Disk

Tags: 12.04

I need to create a minimum Ubuntu live system so as to save my USB Stick space. How do I go about removing a few applications and installing replacements of few others. How do go about doing this. This system should also be installable to my hard-drive for permanent use later.

Answer (score 0):

Remastersys can be used in 12.04 to create a backup of your system for installing to other systems.

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Paste the following lines into the file:

```
# Remastersys
deb http://www.remastersys.com/repository lucid/
```

Update sources:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install remastersys:

```
sudo apt-get install remastersys
```

Once this is done simply modify your system in any way you see fit then create an image file, which you can load onto a usb/cd.